# DROP / CREATE sequence using Oracle in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-manageddataaccess

When I try to run `drop sequence name` like I would any other transaction (`insert, update, delete`), it doesn't work. How can I drop and create sequences from a C# program?

Here is the code

```
    public static bool executeQuery(string query)
    {
        bool success = false;
        DBConnection db = new DBConnection();
        db.Connect();

        if (db.GetConnectionState())
        {
            db.SetSql(query);

            if (db.ExecuteTransactions())
                success = true;
            else
                success = false;
        }
        else
            success = false;

        return success;
    }
```

And the methods `ExecuteTransactions()` and `SetSql()` from DBConnection class,

```
    private OracleConnection connection;
    private OracleCommand command;
    private bool autoDisconnect;

    public bool ExecuteTransactions()
    {

        OracleTransaction transaction = null;
        bool success = false;

        try
        {
            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);

            command.Connection = connection;
            command.Transaction = transaction;

            if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
            {

                transaction.Commit();
                success = true;
            }
            else
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                success = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            success = false;
            autoDisconnect = true;
            throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
        }
        //Cleaning
        finally
        {
            if (transaction != null)
            {
                transaction.Dispose();
            }
            if (autoDisconnect)
            {
                if (command.Parameters.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (OracleParameter pram in command.Parameters)
                    {
                        if (pram.Direction != ParameterDirection.ReturnValue)
                            pram.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                if (command != null)
                {
                    command.Dispose();
                }

                Dispose();
            }
        }
        return success;
    }

    public void SetSql(string sql)
    {
        command = new OracleCommand(sql);
        command.BindByName = true;

    }
```

I'm not sure if the issue is the `SetSql()` method, because `drop sequence` isn't an OracleCommand? Or if its the `ExecuteTransactions()` method, somewhere around the line `if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)`

Thank you!

---

EDIT: This is the error

```
An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in TDS1.exe but was not handled in user code


Additional information: System.InvalidOperationException: OracleCommand.CommandText is invalid


   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.DoPreExecuteProcessing(OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Boolean bXmlQuerySave)


   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

And it says at the line `if (command.ExecuteNonQuery > 0)`

Comment: I've never tried DDL from C#, but I do have this random thought: try wrapping the DDL in an execute immediate (dynamic SQL) like the following: query := "execute immediate 'drop sequence name'";  Be advised that DDL performs an implicit commit before and after the DDL, so side effects can occur if you attempt to combine DDL with other DML statements when attempting to rollback.  In addition: "it doesn't work" isn't a valid Oracle or C# error... so in the future, please provide the error (if applicable) or the behavior if no error is returned.

Comment: @kris, can you please check the edit, I've included the error message